# How to exchange parameter in list in file by new input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("\nParameter you want to change?")
parameter = input(">> ")

someFile = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")

for line in someFile.readlines():
    line = line.split("|")
```

First code searching for string in list after find it, need new input that ask me for new parameter and after receive, need to exchange with new parameter.

**Example:**

> John|Adolfo|johna|john123 ada|Cooper|adac|ada123
>
> input_1 = Adolfo searching input_2 = new parameter exchange in list
>   with input_1

new list :

> John|new parameter(input_2)|johna|john123 ada|Cooper|adac|ada123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to parse or split the string. Simply get the first parameter:

```
parameter = input('Parameter you want to change: ')
```

Open and read the file:

```
f = open(<filename>, 'r').read()
```

If the parameter is found, get the second and replace them:

```
if parameter in f:
    newWord = input('Second parameter to replace with: ')
    newString = f.replace(parameter, newWord)
else:
    print('%s not found.' % parameter)
```

---

**EDIT FOR SAVING TO FILE**

The only change is to clear the opened file after replacing the parameters in the string and rewriting to the file...

Here is the full code including above:

```
parameter = input('Parameter you want to change: ')

f = open(<filename>, 'r+')
contents = f.read()
f.seek(0) #<-- reset the cursor position in file to 0

if parameter in contents:
    newWord = input('Second parameter to replace with: ')
    newString = contents.replace(parameter, newWord)
else:
    print('%s not found.' % parameter)
    newString = contents

f.truncate() #<-- clear the file
f.write(newString) #<-- write the new string to the file
f.close() #<-- close the file to end
```

Comment: Good bless you, you saved me 2 days, Thank you very much.

Comment: @BullzY: If an answer is helpful, remember accept it.

Comment: @m_callens: Hmm...I changed the code format. Always use 4 spaces to format code.

Comment: This doesn't working , parameter isn't saved to file ( replaced with old)

Comment: @BullzY from what you said, the parameters are to be given from user input in the terminal. Is this not true?  EDIT: oh you never specified you wanted to resave the new string to the file.

Comment: @m_callens Thnks, You reduced my pressure.

Comment: How i can now determine input on word?
example:
first input: a
second : ZZZZZ

my file after:
312|foteljZZZZZ snesko|belZZZZZ|15|2900|foteljZZZZZ